# How can I attach an image to an infobox in bing maps?

Tags: bing-maps

Is there a way to put images on an infobox in bing maps? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, supply your own html via the [htmlContent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675210.aspx).  You can make the infobox appear however you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can add HTML through the htmlContent Property, which is added in the options hash.  For example:

```
var infoboxOptions = {
    width :200, 
    height :100, 
    showCloseButton: true,
    zIndex: 0, 
    offset:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10,0), 
    showPointer: true,
    htmlContent:'<img src="source/of/image></img>"'
};
```